# Django `update_last_login` always providing lastest time. not last login time

Tags: django, django-models, django-login

I have logged into my site 1 days ago but today when I login into my site again, it is showing me today's date in `user.last_login` whereas its should display yesterday's date.

Here is the Django source code:-
https://github.com/django/django/blob/a3ba2662cdaa36183fdfb8a26dfa157e26fca76a/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L20

I have also reported to Django(https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28256)

Comment: Wait are you saying `but today when I log into my site` logged out and login or ?

Comment: @RajaSimon I have updated description.

Comment: maybe its due to timezone difference Django by default uses UTC so it may be due to this....yes it is due to time difference so you should update your timezone according to your country in settings.py file

Comment: Are you trolling? when you logged in today and look at the field of course it will tell you that you logged in today. When you want to test that properly you have to make an extra account use incognito mode or another browser, log in and on the next day you check it out with your superuser in the admin.

Comment: @hansTheFranz No, I am not. the question is when I logged in a first time to my site say 12:00 PM and logged out after 2 hours. Now when I log in again at 5:00 PM Django `user.last_login` should show 12:00 PM whereas it shows 5:00 PM the recent login time to me which wrong.

Comment: Sorry Vinay, you are wrong. If you login at 5:00PM then the last time you logged in was at 5:00PM

Comment: @lain that is called recent login time at 5:00PM and  last login was 12:00PM

Comment: I think you misunderstand what last means. last == latest == most recent

Comment: Login specifically refers to the action of logging in, not to the session between logging in and logging out again. Thus, your last/latest/previous/most recent login is actually the time when you logged into your current session, not the time of your previous session.

Answer (score 3):

Check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.last_login) out.

It says last time not the time before this time. I think you misunderstand what last time means. When you write a comment that is the last comment you wrote, not the one before that. So when you Log in again to check when you last logged in THIS is the time Django shows you.

Test the function with two different users. Log in with user1, Log user1 out again. Then go with user2 in the Admin and check the time of user1.

Hope that helps.

p.s. please take down the Ticket...

Answer (score 1):

For those coming here to figure out how to save the previous login time to the current session, you can make your own signal handler for the `user_logged_in` [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals).

Add `previous_login` to your User model:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
...
previous_login = models.DateTimeField(_("previous login"), blank=True, null=True)
```

And then make your own signal handler and disconnect the one offered by django

```
from django.contrib.auth import user_login_failed, user_logged_in
from django.contrib.auth.models import update_last_login
from django.utils import timezone

def update_last_and_previous_login(sender, user, **kwargs):
    user.previous_login = user.last_login
    user.last_login = timezone.now()
    user.save(update_fields=["previous_login", "last_login"])

user_logged_in.disconnect(update_last_login, dispatch_uid="update_last_login")
user_logged_in.connect(update_last_and_previous_login, dispatch_uid="update_last_and_previous_login")
```